# Multidimensional array as argument in C++/CLI

Tags: multidimensional-array, c++-cli

I am getting a bit desperate. :) Is there any possible way to make this in C++/CLI? It's a C# code.

```
void test(int[,] numbers) { ... }
```

---

More specifically I am trying to make an "universal" marshaller (as an extension to `marshal_as`), able to convert `int[2,2]` to `int**` (by copy).

Something like this (which is for one-dimensional array):

```
// cli::array<TYPE> -> TYPE*
template <typename TTo, typename TFromType> 
TTo marshal_as(cli::array<TFromType>^ const from) 
{ 
   ... 
}
```

Comment: You'll have to use proper C++/CLI syntax, it is `array<int, 2>^`.  If it has to be "universal" and work for arrays of any rank then it must be Array^.  Do avoid copying large arrays and favor pin_ptr<> so you can have native code party directly on the array content.

Comment: @Hans: Correct, except that since this is a template helper class internal to C++/CLI, it can be `array<int, Rank>^` where `Rank` is a template argument.  Only need to use `System::Array^` if the rank can vary at runtime.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, it works. I was trying to do that before, but probably make something wrong.
   
@BenVoigt: Possible to be more specific? Becase that's exactly what I want, but am unable to make it. I always end up with `expected compile-time constant expression`.

Comment: You'll need to ignore Voigt's comment, Array::Rank is a variable.